# How to fix Ahref error showing wordpress admin pages as "Duplicate pages without canonical"?

Tags: wp-redirect, rel-canonical

I am using Ahref tool for performing a site audit on a WordPress based site. The site audit shows an error "Duplicate pages without canonicals" with a page count of 110. When I check the details all the duplicate pages are wordpress admin pages. For example "https://www.example.com/login.php", "https://www.example.com/login.php?redirect_to=https://www.example.com/some-blog-post".

I can not find a way to solve this issue.

Solutions tried so far:

1 - Tried blocking wp-admin and wp-login pages through robots.txt (didn't work)
2 - Tried using plugin "wp-hide login page" (didn't work)

I am unable to understand why Ahref is fetching the wp-admin pages and labeling them as non-canonical urls. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Do we have any way around to fix this issue?

Thank you for taking time to read my query.

Looking forward -

Comment: You have probably a login link on your site. If Ahref doesn't respect the robots.txt, there is nothing you can do aside from using some better tool. Technically this is not a problem at all.